# Ten fetters in saṃsāra during meditation

Tags: theravada, enlightenment, meditation-insight

How are the 10 fetters being destroyed?

Can the chain of fetters be seen during vipassana meditation?

Answer (score 1):

The 10 fetters are destroyed by reaching the different stages of enlightenment.
Meaning the Sotāpanna gets rid off the first three fetters; the fourth and fifth are weakened by the Sakadāgāmi and completely destroyed by the Anāgāmī.
Fully free of all the fetters is the Arahant.
See http://www.palikanon.com/english/wtb/s_t/samyojana.htm) for a short list.

I'm not sure what you mean by the chain of fetters. Could you specify this?
Anyway, yes the fetters can be seen/experienced during vipassana meditation.

Comment: Chain of fetter ,what I mean is  chain of stage of fetter can be seen and at the last stage it has disappeared. And there is a nother chain appears can seen.

Comment: The fetters are not a chain, in the sense that they are linked to each other one after the other. They are separate mental states, mental attributes. But maybe I still don't understand what you mean.
Perhaps you mean 'one is chained to a fetter'.

Anyhow, my original answer still stands. The fetters are destroyed by reaching enlightenment.
And one will, without any doubt, know when fetters have been destroyed.

Comment: Chain ,Is it samadhi state of mind?

Comment: Chain is basically a different word than fetter, but they both refer to the same: Being tide to whatever (craving, ideas and so on). It has nothing to do with samadhi. If you are able to see YouTube, you might be interested in watching this video on Fetters (MN 64): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxNQSPhlu60&t=0s&index=39&list=PL4j9bs3T1aPSuZ4ULqx2QkFvrZMU-mXrz

Answer (score 1):

> How are the 10 fetters being destroyed?

To breaking the circuit of 10 fetters, the practitioner has to destroy by [the continuous understanding](https://unmixedtheravada.blogspot.com/search/label/Pa%E1%B9%ADiccasamupp%C4%81da) the circuit, paṭiccasamuppāda, of 10 fetters [as they are](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/26702/10100).

In [breaking of circuit](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka2/v.php?B=16&A=33&Z=87&eng=buddhavacana), paṭiloma-paṭiccasamuppāda, Buddha taught to destroy the last fetter, avijjā and taṇhā&upādāna, to break the whole circuit. But most some people can not immediately destroy avijjā and taṇhā&upādāna.

So, in [10 fetters](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/v.php?B=24&A=418&Z=427&eng=buddhavacana), Buddha describe more explanation of those avijjā and taṇhā&upādāna as 10 fetters, 10 saṃyojana. And Buddha arranged that 10 fetters from the easiest-to-destroy to the hardest-to-destroy. So, someone, who can not destroy avijjā and taṇhā&upādāna at only one time, will try to destroy the easier-to-destroy fetters (such as uddhambhāgiya-saṃyojana) instead, step by step.

By this way, people can more easily destroy avijjā and taṇhā&upādāna, by beginning at destroying 3 orambhāgiya-fetters, which are diṭṭhi-upādāna/sīpabata-upādāna/attvāda-upādāna-paṭiccasamuppāda, =iterations of bhava&vibhava-taṇhā-paṭiccasamuppāda, and  ignoring [avijjā] of causes&effects in paṭiccasamuppāda. After they destroyed these 3 fetters, the 7 left fetters will certainly destroy in the future, not over more than 7 rebirth according to Sutta. Aṅ. (3): chakkanipātā,  Paṭhama-[abhabbaṭṭhānasuttaṃ](http://84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=22&A=10315&eng=metta_e) and the suttas around it.

> Can the chain of fetters be seen during vipassana meditation?

Yes, according to Sutta. Saṃ. Ma. [Dhammacakkappavattanasutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/v.php?B=19&A=10037&Z=10104&eng=buddhavacana), the practitioner have to clearly understand [the 4 noble truths](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/v.php?B=14&A=9020&Z=9160&eng=accesstoinsight_than), which included 10 fetters in the 2nd noble truth, already.